# Passing a Clojure function as java.util.Function

Tags: java, clojure, interop

As in topic, I'd like to use a Java method taking a Function as an argument and provide it with a `Clojure` function, be it anonymous or a regular one. Anyone has any idea how to do that?

Comment: `(reify java.util.function.Function)`?

Comment: The `reify` approach works but is overly verbose. I think we're going to see more and more Java APIs using the functional interfaces in `java.util.function`, so it would be good to fix this in Clojure itself. Clojure functions already implement `Runnable` and `Callable`.

Comment: @glts are you aware of any discussion on the topic of extending the `java.util.function.Function` interface for `java.lang.IFn` or have `java.lang.AFn` implement it?
It's still not done and I'm wondering why?
https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/43873e477dff33e5c53323bf8ceddc014b870a40/src/jvm/clojure/lang/IFn.java#L23
Could it be that the `Function` also has a `compose` & `andThen` method, besides the main `apply`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`java.util.function.Function` is an interface.
You need to implement the abstract method [`apply(T t)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#apply-T-).
Something like this should do it:

```clj
(defn hello [name]
  (str "Hello, " name "!"))

(defn my-function[]
  (reify 
    java.util.function.Function
    (apply [this arg]
      (hello arg))))

;; then do (my-function) where you need to pass in a Function
```

Answer (score 7):

Terje's accepted answer is absolutely correct. But you can make it a little easier to use with a first-order function:

```
(defn ^java.util.function.Function as-function [f]
  (reify java.util.function.Function
    (apply [this arg] (f arg))))
```

or a macro:

```
(defmacro jfn [& args]
  `(as-function (fn ~@args)))
```

Comment: also see https://ask.clojure.org/index.php/767/integration-with-java-util-function-interfaces?show=8410#a8410