# Dealing with Java Optional<T> in clojure

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am writing Clojure code interacting with external Java library. One of the method returns Java `Optional` object. Let's assume that it returns `Optional<String>` and I need to change the string value in the `Optional` object, for example, to lowercase. I'd use `map` method if I write the code in Java:

```
Optional<String> ret = someObj.someMethod();
ret.map(String::toLowerCase)
   .map(...)
   .orElse("x");
```

So, I need to call `someObj.someMethod()` in Clojure and have to do the similar work. What I found is this: [Passing a Clojure function as java.util.Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525255/passing-a-clojure-function-as-java-util-function)

So I wrote code like this:

```
(defn ^java.util.function.Function jfn [f]
  (reify java.util.function.Function
    (apply [this arg] (f arg))))

(let [ret (.someMethod someObj)]
  (.. ret
      (map (jfn (fn [x] (s/lower-case x))))
      (map (jfn (...)))
      (orElse "x")))
```

In order to pass clojure function to the place that expects Java lambda, I used `jfn` defined like the above. And actually it works fine.

But I am not sure this is the best way to do this as I have to wrap clojure function that calls Java method inside with Java's `Function`.

Are there any better/simpler way to do this? It will be better if we can call Java `String`'s `toLowerCase` method directly.

Comment: I'm not sure if it fits your use case, but you could "unbox" the `Optional` early on, and use `some->` macro to do a similar operation. Even if you needed an `Optional` with the value later, it might be easier to re-box the value later than to do Function interop.

Comment: @TaylorWood Thanks for your feedback. I think your idea is valid and worth to be an answer.

Comment: I like your first approach better. If you don't like boxing, and your functions are all literals, you could make `jfn` a macro instead of a function: `(defmacro jfn [[arg] & body] (reify Function (apply [_# ~arg] ~@body)))`, and then `(.map ret (jfn [x] (s/lower-case x)))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it fits your use case, but you could "unbox" the `Optional` early on, and use `some->` macro to do similar short-circuit-on-null function composition.

Even if you needed an `Optional` with the value later, it might be easier to unbox the value early and re-box the value later, rather than `Function` interop.

```
(defn optional->nilable [this]
  (when (.isPresent this)
    (.get this)))

(def maybe (Optional/of " something "))

(some-> (optional->nilable maybe)
        (clojure.string/trim)
        (not-empty)
        (clojure.string/upper-case))
; => "SOMETHING"
```

Then if you needed to convert back to `Optional`:

```
(Optional/ofNullable *1)
```

Comment: You could also unwrap inline, `(some-> (.orElse maybe nil) ,,,)` …